# ArgumentException when using Graphics.DrawLines

Tags: c#

I am using visual studio express 2012.

I am trying to draw the NRZI signal. But whenever I run my program I always get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

The error is somewhere in the `draws.DrawLines(Pens.Red, NRZI);`

Can somebody tell me why?

Here is my code:

```
Graphics draws;
Point[] NRZI = new Point[592]; // each binary value equals 74 pixels wide
string data = "10101010";

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    int x = 0;

    if (comboBox1.Text == "NRZI") 
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < data.Length; c++)
        {

            if (data.ToCharArray()[c] == '0') // check if binary value is 0
            {
                for (int p = 0; p < 74; p++)
                {
                    NRZI[x] = new Point(x, 109); // point to signify 0 or low
                    x++;
                }
            }
            if (data.ToCharArray()[c] == '1') // check if binary value is 1
            {
                for (int p = 0; p < 74; p++)
                {
                    NRZI[x] = new Point(x, 9);  // point to signify 1 or high
                    x++;
                }                        
            }
        }
        this.Refresh(); // calls paint
        for (w = 0; w < pictureBox1.Width; w++)
        {
            draws.DrawLines(Pens.Red, NRZI);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `NRZI`on the point of the exception?

Comment: A lot of *magic*: *words* (`NRZI`) and *numbers* (`74`, `592`, `109`)

Comment: 592/74 = 8 so I assume `data` has 8 elements at max? and why are you `for (w = 0; w < pictureBox1.Width; w++) { draws.DrawLines(Pens.Red, NRZI); }` ? It loops `width` times over whole number of "pixels" in width, but it draws the same thing in each iteration!

Comment: My bad, that is NRZ. In telecommunication, a non-return-to-zero (NRZ) line code is a binary code in which on 1's are represented by one significant condition, usually a positive voltage, while 0's are represented by some other significant condition, usually a negative voltage, with no other neutral or rest condition. Yes u are right there are 8 elements each with 74 pixels. If you try to look at the code above, when data is 1, it sets points for a line to be drawn above the zero reference, when it is 0 it does the opposite. The drawlines will draw all the point. And thanks, I found the mistake

Comment: It was the refresh(), so dumb of me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you use the wrong `Graphics` object. In the paint event handler, you need to use the `PaintEventArgs.Graphics` property of the supplied `PaintEventArgs e` argument:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Red, NRZI);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now. The problem was that the graphics object was **disposed**. So every property and method of it would throw this exception. I give this answer in case someone else stumbles over it.